# SQL stored procedure: how to concatenate parameter value?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, parameters, concatenation

This is original code:

```
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'TestStep', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
        @command=N'/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\FolderName\ProjectName\PackageName.dtsx\"" /SERVER localhost /ENVREFERENCE 9 /Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";1 /Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E', 
        @database_name=N'master', ...
```

I want to do something like this (replace value after `ENVREFERENCE` in long string with dynamic value):

```
DECLARE @myVariable int
SET @myVariable = 10

EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'TestStep', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=1, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=0, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
        @command=N'/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\AccuCenter\AccuCenterDBImport\VehicleMake.dtsx\"" /SERVER localhost /ENVREFERENCE ' + @myVariable + N' /Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";1 /Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E', 
        @database_name=N'master'
```

Comment: ... + cast(@myVariable as varchar(10) ) +  ...

Comment: **Which** RDBMS ?!?!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't you put the whole in a variable ?

```
DECLARE @myCommand nvarchar(max)
SET @myCommand = N'/ISSERVER "\"\SSISDB\AccuCenter\AccuCenterDBImport\VehicleMake.dtsx\"" /SERVER localhost /ENVREFERENCE '
    + LTRIM(STR(@myVariable))
    + N' /Par "\"$ServerOption::LOGGING_LEVEL(Int16)\"";1 /Par "\"$ServerOption::SYNCHRONIZED(Boolean)\"";True /CALLERINFO SQLAGENT /REPORTING E'
```

By the way, you could build it entirely to fit your needs.

Then use it when calling **sp_add_jobstep**:

```
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep
                @job_id=@jobId,
                @step_name=N'TestStep', 
                @step_id=1, 
                @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
                @on_success_action=1, 
                @on_success_step_id=0, 
                @on_fail_action=2, 
                @on_fail_step_id=0, 
                @retry_attempts=0, 
                @retry_interval=0, 
                @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'SSIS', 
                @command=@myCommand
                @database_name=N'master'
```